# How do I change the CGRect to buttons?

Tags: swift

I originally used rectangles to test out the program but now I need to make them buttons. How would I do that programmatically?

```
import UIKit
```

class interestViewController: UIViewController {

```
var squareView: UIView!
var square: UIView!
var frogs: UIView!
var colson: UIView!
var wwdc: UIView!
var gravity: UIGravityBehavior!
var animator: UIDynamicAnimator!
var collision: UICollisionBehavior!
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    squareView = UIView(frame: CGRectMake(100, 100, 100, 100))





    view.addSubview(squareView)
    animator = UIDynamicAnimator(referenceView: view)



    squareView.backgroundColor = UIColor.blackColor()
    gravity = UIGravityBehavior(items: [squareView])
    animator.addBehavior(gravity)
    collision = UICollisionBehavior(items: [squareView])
    collision.translatesReferenceBoundsIntoBoundary = true
    animator.addBehavior(collision)


    // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
}

override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
    super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}
```

}

Answer (score 0):

Question: How would I do that programmatically?

Short answer: Don't. Create your buttons in IB. It's easier than code the first time, and way, waaaaay easier to update and maintain. Learn to use IB. It's a huge timesaver.

If you are bound and determined to do things the hard way, then you'll need to use one of the UIButton class initializers, like buttonWithType. Then you'd set the frame and other attributes like you're doing with your squareView.

Comment: What's with the down vote? I recommended a different approach, but also told the OP how to do it in code if he/she really wants to.

Comment: instead of changing the rectangles into boxes, I just created buttons on the storyboard, but when I run it the blocks fall and cover the buttons. Is there anyway to bring the buttons to the front. I created an @IBAction for the button.

Comment: You can reorder the items in the storyboard to change their Z order. You could also drag your buttons inside your rectangle views and they would move together. I'm not clear on what you're trying to do, so it's a bit hard to advise.

Comment: I tried changing the order but nothing happened. This is how it looks                                                                     http://puu.sh/hqXuJ/c1decf165f.png

Comment: That link points to a tiny blue rectangle and nothing else. How are your readers supposed to learn anything about your problem from that. You need to explain what you are trying to do, and show your view hierarchy, with constraints, if we are to understand what's going on.